How to calculate intersection points of diameters with an inner circle?
I am working on a visualisation project where I am attempting to create a circle illusion using moving dots along the diameters of a larger circle. To achieve this effect, I need to calculate the initial starting positions of these moving dots.
Imagine two circles:

A larger circle with radius $R$ centred at $(0, 0)$.
A smaller circle with radius $R/2$ centred at $(R/2, 0)$.

I drew several diameters on the larger circle, each with an equal angle between them. All these diameters intersect the smaller circle at the common point $(0, 0)$.
My goal is to calculate:

The second intersection points of these diameters with the smaller circle.
The distance from the centre of the larger circle $(0, 0)$ to these intersection points.

Here's an image illustrating the setup:


Welcome to Mathematics Stackexchange! Please can you tell us what you have tried?

Image describing the intersection for an arbitrary diameter making an angle of theta with the smaller circle
Let $O$ be the origin, $EOF$ be an arbitrary diameter of the bigger circle that intersects the smaller circle at point $C$. Let $EOF$ make an anlge of $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. Let $OB$ be the diameter of the smaller circle along $x$-axis. Now, the traingle $OCB$ is a right-angled triangle with $\angle OCB = 90^{\circ}$ as any diameter of a circle subtends a right angle to any point on the circle. Let $A$ be a point on the diameter $OB$ where the perpendicular from $C$ intersects $OB$. Now, the traingle $ABC$ is a right-angled triangle with $\angle CAB = 90^{\circ}$ and the triangle $AOC$ is a right-angled triangle with $\angle CAO = 90^{\circ}$. Thus we have $\angle COB = \angle BCA = \theta$. By trigonometric properties, we have $|OC| = |OB|\cos{\theta} = R\cos{\theta}$ and $|CB| = |OB|\sin{\theta} = R\sin{\theta}$. We also have $|CA| = |CB|\cos{\theta} = R\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$ and $|OB| = |OC|\cos{\theta} = R\cos{\theta}\cos{\theta} = R\cos^{2}{\theta}$. Thus the point $C$ has the co-ordinates $(R\cos^{2}{\theta}, R\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})$. Thus the distance from the origin is equal to $\sqrt{(R\cos^{2}{\theta})^2 + (R\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})^2} = \sqrt{R^2\cos^{4}{\theta} + R^2\sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}} = \sqrt{R^2\cos^2{\theta}(\cos^2{\theta} + \sin^2{\theta})} = \sqrt{R^2\cos^2{\theta}} = R\cos{\theta}$. For example if a diameter makes a $30^{\circ}$ angle with the horizintal, then it intersects the smaller circle at the point $(\frac{3R}{4},\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{4})$ and the distance to this point from origin is $\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}$.
